# Pandas: convert for loop with if/else conditions into apply method (lambda function)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, vectorization, apply

I have the following function with for loop:

```
def add_CQI_iterrows(df):
    previous_row = df['Date'].astype(str)[0]
    CQI_index = 0
    series = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['Date'] == previous_row:       
            previous_row = row['Date']
            print(CQI_index)
        else:
            CQI_index += 1
            previous_row = row['Date']      
        series.append(CQI_index)
    df['CQI'] = series
    
    return df
```

I would like to find a way to convert this for-loop into apply method. Something like this (doesn't work):

```
def add_CQI_apply(df):
    previous_row = df['Date'].astype(str)[0]
    CQI_index = 1
    series = []
    
    df['CQI'] = df.apply(lambda row: previous_row = row['Date'] if row['Date'] == previous_row else CQI_index += 1 and previous_row = row['Date'], axis=1)
    
    return df
```

I want to do this conversion because I want to take a look at how fast apply method is and whether it possible or not to do vectorization of the apply method over Pandas series.

Here is my data (data.json):

```
[
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 8:50",
   "UE": 1
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 8:50",
   "UE": 2
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 8:50",
   "UE": 3
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 8:57",
   "UE": 1
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 8:57",
   "UE": 8
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 8:57",
   "UE": 2
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 9:12",
   "UE": 1
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 9:12",
   "UE": 5
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 9:12",
   "UE": 3
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 9:20",
   "UE": 1
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 9:20",
   "UE": 4
 },
 {
   "Date": "9/20/2020 9:20",
   "UE": 3
 }
]
```

Finally here is function to upload this data:

```
def upload_data(file):
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S") 
    df['CQI'] = np.nan
    return df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['CQI'] = (df['Date'] != df['Date'].shift()).cumsum()`

```py
In [120]: (df['Date'] != df['Date'].shift()).cumsum()
Out[120]:
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    4
11    4
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```